# Autocomplete prevents suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using certain autocompletes in VSCode, it semi-highlights anything I type and doesn't provide suggestions until I focus out of the area. Any way to prevent this?

[image: example of autocomplete not providing suggestions]

(the `clg` command is from the `JavaScript (ES6) code snippets` extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting you're looking for is:

```
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
```

Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to force open the suggestion list.

Answer (score 0):

Press `ctrl+space`. It will give suggestions